# Fetch transactions from Stripe::Transfer with latest stripe version

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe latest version in production.

When I try to fetch transactions:

> Stripe::Transfer.all.first.transactions

I fount, there is no transactions method for latest Stripe::Transfer

```
 undefined method `transactions' for #<Stripe::Transfer
```

Stripe API is upgrades:
2014-08-04

```
The transactions, summary, and other_transfers properties in automatic transfer responses have been removed in favor of the balance history endpoint (/v1/balance/history), which can be called with the transfer id (using the ?transfer= parameter) to filter transactions by transfer.
```

So How we fetch transactions from Stripe transfer ?

But its working fine with Stripe old version.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options depending on what you want. If you a certain level of detail for charges you can fetch all the charges associated with a transfer which will fetch only that:

```
var options = {};
stripe.transfers.listTransactions(id, options);
```

If, on the other hand, you would like something more akin to the old summary object then I would get the balances associated with the transfer:

```
var options =  { transfer: id };
stripe.balance.listTransactions(options);
```

The balances returned will contain a variety of balance types - the first one refers to the actual transfer as a whole and can be ignored and the rest is a combo of charges, refunds, adjustments, etc including the fees for each.

In both the above cases `id` refers to the transfer ID. Note that you will need to loop through these to fetch all items - this can be done in a couple of ways as listed under [Pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#pagination). In the above cases, I check if the result contains the `has_more: true` field and, if so, loop through again using the `starting_after: X` addecd to the `options` object where X is the ID of the last charge/balance returned on previous call.